# How to update chart elements after changing time domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

First of all, let me be clear on this: i'm a d3 newbie!

So, i have a chart based on utc time domain. the domain is one of this: *1 day | 3 days*, and I can switch from one to the other with a user action.

Refreshing / transitioning the x to represent 24hs to 72hs is working properly, but I'm having difficulties to update the elements that are already in the chart. Some how it seems that after changing the domain `.data()` `.enter()` won't actually enter *(so my attr don't get updated)*.

[This](http://jsbin.com/moyararago/edit?html,js,output) is a jsbin with the full example of my problem. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow [this series of examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) very carefully.

Here is the problem code corrected ...

```
      group.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'flight');

      group.attr('transform', function (trip) {
        return 'translate(' + hourDomain(      Math.min.apply(null, _.map(trip.legs, 'departureDateTime'))) + ', 60)';
        });
```

The problem is that you are applying the positioning to the enter selection only: only new nodes. After the first call, the enter selection is always empty because there are no new nodes. The linked examples will explain it.